# Problem starting Gunicorn Web Service using Systemd

Tags: systemd

I have a problem running a Gunicorn Web service using Systemd.

Here are the files I created in order to execute:

The shell script file (/home/ubuntu/mata.sh):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cd /home/ubuntu/workspace/test-api
/home/ubuntu/workspace/mata_venv/bin/gunicorn --workers=4 app:app --bind 0.0.0.0:xxxx
```

Here's my .service file (/lib/systemd/system/mata.service):

```
[Unit]
Description=Test API Service
After=multi-user.target
Conflicts=getty@tty1.service

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/mata.sh
StandardInput=tty-force

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Running the shell script on its own works well, but when running `systemctl status mata.service`, I am getting the following message:

```
Started Test API Service
mata.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=216/GROUP
mata.service: Unit entered failed state.
mata.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Any idea?

Comment: The sequencing here is throwing me off a little bit; are you starting it manually and then running `systemctl status...`? You are starting it with systemctl, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [systemd - My custom service exits with status code 216/GROUP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/374273/systemd-my-custom-service-exits-with-status-code-216-group)

Comment: @JdeBP, I don't see that the user set a `Group=` definition here; is the implication that `User=ubuntu` is failing because of that user's groups? (The other aspect of the duplicate answer relates to using `nobody`, and seems unrelated to me)

Comment: [systemd exit code 216](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#id-1.20.8) indicates "Failed to determine or change group credentials."

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yep, I am trying to start it with systemctl start mata.service

Comment: Is there anything unusual about the output of `groups ubuntu`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a "Type=simple" service, you have a forking service, since it's not the "mata.sh" process that you care about, it's the "gunicorn" process.

For a Type=simple service, change the `[Service]` section to:

```
[Service]
User=ubuntu
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/workspace/test-api
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/workspace/mata_venv/bin/gunicorn --workers=4 app:app --bind 0.0.0.0:xxxx
StandardInput=tty-force
```

... where I imported the `cd` command with a [WorkingDirectory](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#) directive.

Or make it a Forking service with:

```
[Service]
User=ubuntu
Type=forking
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/mata.sh
StandardInput=tty-force
```

You may prefer the Type=forking solution if, as it appears, the gunicorn process starts sub-processes (workers=4).

Comment: See also http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html which has a sample systemd service file.

Comment: Hmmmm, getting the same error.. Any other suggestions?