# How to fix `start-limit-hit` trying to start gunicorn on ubuntu 18?

Tags: systemd

I am trying to start gunicorn on bootup of my machine but when I check the status of my service after enabling and starting it I get an error starting `start-limit-hit`. I have tried using `sudo systemctl restart ssh` as suggested in [How to resolve service start limit hit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1089310/how-to-resolve-service-start-limit-hit). This is my `.service` file:

```
[Unit]
Requires=myproject.socket
After = network.target

[Service]
Restart=always
User=ubuntu
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/myproject
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/myproject/venv36/bin/gunicorn -w 1 -b 0.0.0.0:8080 wsgi:$
Type=simple


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My `.socket` file:

```
[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/myproject/socket

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

Comment: You can run `systemctl reset-failed <YOUR_UNIT>` to get rid of the start-limit error. Regarding your `.service` file I would suggest to remove the whitespaces in `After = network.target`, although I'm not sure if that will help starting the service.

Comment: I removed the spaces and ran `systemctl reset-failed <YOUR_UNIT>` but still got the start-limit-hit error

Comment: ok, just to be clear, you did replace `<YOUR_UNIT>` with the actual name of your unit, right?

Comment: yeah! I used `systemctl reset-failed myproject`

Comment: Since you've not told anyone _how the service is failing_, what the error messages logged are, people are going to flounder around blindly with the problem diagnosis.  For all that the world knows, you too could be having the error in https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/501590/5132 .  [Always follow the standard litany](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/problem-report-standard-litany.html).

Answer (score 3):

You have `Restart=always` and a `Type` of `simple`, so in case the program specified in `ExecStart` is a daemon that forks another process and exits, your app will be considered not-active -> it will restart until it hits the limit.

You should either pass a parameter for the program to remain in the foreground, or change the `Type` to `forking`. After that run `systemctl reset-failed myproject` and start it.

Comment: This is not the case for Gunicorn, as M. Schaller no doubt remembers from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/501592/5132 .  `Type=forking` is a bad idea that is best avoided, moreover.